# D3 - flare not showing all data

Tags: d3.js

Here is the code I'm working with. I'm generating data in php and sending that to d3 via json:

1. php file:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <style>
   path {
     stroke: #fff;
   }

   </style>
   <body>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">        </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="flare.js"></script>

   <?php

   // Move php data to JSON to be used in d3 apps

   $flare_child_1 = array("name"=> "subchild1", "size"=> 90);
   $flare_child_2 = array("name"=> "subchild2", "size"=> 10);
   $flare_child_3 = array("name"=> "subchild3", "size"=> 55);
   $flare_child_4 = array("name"=> "subchild4", "size"=> 72);
   $flare_child_5 = array("name"=> "subchild5", "size"=> 60);
   $flare_children_1[] =  $flare_child_1;
   $flare_children_1[] =  $flare_child_2;
   $flare_children_1[] =  $flare_child_3;
   $flare_children_1[] =  $flare_child_4;
   $flare_children_1[] =  $flare_child_5;
   $flare_children[] = array('name'=> "first", 'children'=>$flare_children_1);
   $flare = array('name'=> "flare", 'children'=>$flare_children);



   echo "<script> var root = "; echo json_encode($flare); echo ";"; 
   echo "input_data(root);</script>"; 

   ?>

   </body>
   ```
2. js file

   ```
   var width = 960,
       height = 700,
       radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 10;

   var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");

   var x = d3.scale.linear()
       .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

   var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
       .range([0, radius]);

   var color = d3.scale.category20c();

   var partition = d3.layout.partition()
       .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

   var arc = d3.svg.arc()
       .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI,x(d.x))); })
       .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI,x(d.x + d.dx))); })
       .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
       .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });



   function getRootmostAncestorByRecursion(node) {
       return node.depth > 1 ? getRootmostAncestorByRecursion(node.parent) : node;
   }

   function input_data(root) {
     var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2) + ")");

     svg.selectAll("path")
       .data(partition.nodes(root))
       .enter().append("path")
       .attr("d", arc)
       .style("fill", function(d) {
         return color(getRootmostAncestorByRecursion(d).name);
       })
       .on("click", click)
       .append("title")
       .text(function(d) {
         return d.name + "\n" + formatNumber(d.value);
       });
   }


   function click(d) {
     svg.transition()
         .duration(750)
         .tween("scale", function() {
           var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
               yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
               yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
           return function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); };
         })
       .selectAll("path")
         .attrTween("d", function(d) { return function() { return arc(d);}; });
   }

   d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
   ```

I'm expecting something similar to this https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4348373/

but all I'm seeing a blue spot. The children don't feature. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Disclaimer, I don't know anything about `php`.  Does the `<?php` execute before the `<script type="text/javascript" src="flare.js"></script>`?

Comment: No the <script that's before the <?php executes before the php code. That's why I made the function input_data(root). Else all of the javascript code would run before the data was created in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things wrong here.

First, while you are correct path creation is wrapped in a function and will execute after the `php` code but your `svg` creation will execute **before** the body tag, so you'll never get an `svg` tag.

Second, your JSON is malformed.  I executed the `php` and it produces:

```
<script>
var root = {
  "name": "flare",
  "children": {
    "name": "first",
    "children": [{
      "name": "subchild1",
      "size": 90
    }, {
      "name": "subchild2",
      "size": 10
    }, {
      "name": "subchild3",
      "size": 55
    }, {
      "name": "subchild4",
      "size": 72
    }, {
      "name": "subchild5",
      "size": 60
    }]
  }
};
input_data(root);
```

Notice, that the first `children` is an object and not an array of objects.

Putting these two things together [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/p62f3MP8S3ltLw9fvfjO?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.